# What does min and max mean when sort is "activity" or "hot"?

Tags: discussion, sort

Does they mean anything actually? There was an "issue" when you needed to add min=0 to [queries](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions) to actually get the answers instead of nothing. Just checked that this is not the case anymore, but was wondering what min and max actually meant.

EDIT: if sort is "votes", then min and max is really a "unix epoch date, range [0, 253,402,300,799]"? are negative values supported in this case?

Answer (score 2):

'hot', 'week', 'month' return questions with high activity and interest within a period of time relative to now.

`min/max` further limit those results.

see [How to use min/max with sort](https://stackapps.com/questions/922) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna confirm this as a bug in the docs.

For the `votes` sort `min` and `max` are just numbers, not dates.

I'll update this answer when this is fixed.

Comment: What can min and max look like if things are sorted alphabetically? See the tags endpoint.  Or, can min/max be a viewcount as well?

Comment: @jjnguy - in alphanumeric cases (such as sorting by `name`) `min` and `max` are an alphanumberic range.  So, you could get every user with a name between `A` and `B`, for instance.