# How to use min/max with sort

Tags: discussion, dev-tip

While some sort values make inference of the expected min/max values less than ambiguous, others do not.

Pending formal documentation, I hope this can serve as an informal reference.

**Aggregated sort values and corresponding min/max datatype**

- `activity` : `unix timestamp` - last activity date range (includes *any* activity?)
- `creation` : `unix timestamp` - creation date range
- `added` : `unix timestamp` - added date range
- `reputation` : `integer` - reputation count range
- `views` : `integer` - view count range
- `votes` : `integer` - vote count range
- `popular` : `integer` - tag count range
- `name` : `string` - case insensitive range. e.g. to find exact match for users with `display_name` 'joey' you can send `min=joey&max=joey`
- `featured` : `unix timestamp` - last activity date range (includes *any* activity?)
- `hot` : `unix timestamp` - last activity date range (includes *any* activity?)
- `month` : `unix timestamp` - last activity date range (includes *any* activity?)
- `week` : `unix timestamp` - last activity date range (includes *any* activity?)

Special Sorts:

These sorts return the questions that are displayed on the front page of the site under the tab of the same name. `min/max` will further limit those sets to questions with a `last_activity` date that falls within that range.

- `featured` : Questions with an active bounty
- `hot` : Questions with the most interest/activity in the last few day
- `week` : Questions with the most interest/activity in the last week
- `month` : Questions with the most interest/activity in the last month

You can follow the comment trail on [min/max parameters are incorrectly documented as date - confusion and crippled libraries ensue](https://stackapps.com/questions/671) for some more info that may be edifying.

Comment: Added is a `date` and featured is also a `date` i believe.

Comment: Also is it not a unix timestamp rather than a date?

Comment: @john - yes, but outside of the context of the json transport we deal with these values as dates, do we not? that is the spirit in which the question is offered.

Comment: @code Phew that's okay then. I thought the api had changed again. ;-)

Comment: @john, you do bring up a good point. i know what i mean, assuming that others will is a mistake. remedy now. thanks for the head check.

Comment: @john - you can follow http://twitter.com/soapiwatch on twitter and be notified whenever the api changes. see http://stackapps.com/questions/534 for more info